# Name Error - uninitialized constant Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, search

I'm adding search functionality to my ruby on rails app. Based on the Ryan Bates tutorial #111.

For some reason, my render call in my show page is resulting in

```
Name Error
uninitialized constant Search::Properties
```

**My controller is simple**

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @search = Search.new
    end

    def create
        @search = Search.create(search_params)
        redirect_to @search
    end

    def show
        @search = Search.find(params[:id])
    end

    private

    def search_params
        params.require(:search).permit(:keywords, :category, :min_price, :max_price, :bedrooms, :bathrooms, :garage)
    end

end
```

**And I created a new class in my model**

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base

    def properties
        properties = Properties.all
        properties = properties.order(:title)
        properties = properties.where(["title LIKE ?","%#{keywords}%"]) if keywords.present?
        properties = properties.where([category: category]) if category.present?
        properties = properties.where(["price >= ?","%#{min_price}%"]) if min_price.present?
        properties = properties.where(["price <= ?","%#{max_price}%"]) if max_price.present?
        properties = properties.where(["bedrooms == ?","%#{bedrooms}%"]) if bedrooms.present?
        properties = properties.where(["bathrooms == ?","%#{bathrooms}%"]) if bathrooms.present?
        properties = properties.where(["garage == ?","%#{garage}%"]) if garage.present?

        properties
    end

end
```

**And my view**

```
<div class="row property-list-wrapper">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="col-md-8 property-list-left">
      <h1>We've found <%= pluralize(@properties.count, 'property')%> </h1>

      <%= render @properties %>


    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 property-list-right">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It seems that my render tag is not finding the class in my model. Am I missing something in my controller maybe?

I'm using rails 4.2.7 and ruby 2.2.4p230

Comment: Have you defined the class `Properties`?

Comment: The call to `Properties.all` inside your `Search` model is being scoped to the class. You can try `::Properties.all` to get outside the `Search` scope although to be honest the issue is bigger than that. Does your search model have a corresponding database table? If not, why inherit from ActiveRecord::Base? Also, model class names should be singular.

Comment: Turns out you are both right and I made a rookie error. I defined the class Properties and I should have been using singular Property in my search model. Thanks for your help guys, very quick responses to.